# Problema, "My application has stopped" - "SQLiteException: no such table"

Tags: android-studio, sqlite, base-de-datos, genymotion

He creado una App para consultar la direccion de una persona colocando su nombre en un EditText, para la base de datos he usado el programa BD Browser para SQlite, cree un folder llamado assets y coloque alli el archivo .db. La apliacion abre en el emulador, pero al presionar el boton para buscar me aparece el error "Unfortunaly, My application has stopped" y se cierra.
Gracias por cualquier ayuda

Otros datos:
El emulador es Genymotion, use un dispositivo generico 5.0.0 API 21.

Los errores del logcat son los siguientes:

```
12-13 14:30:59.555 2211-2211/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown         
/acct/uid_10059: Read-only file system
12-13 14:31:02.606 2211-2211/com.example.propietario.myapplication 
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: Table1
12-13 14:31:02.607 2211-2211/com.example.propietario.myapplication 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.propietario.myapplication, PID: 2211
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Table1 (code 1): , 
while compiling: Select Address from Table1 where Name =''
    at 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native 
Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
    at com.example.propietario.myapplication.DataBaseAccess.getAddress(DataBaseAccess.java:48)
    at com.example.propietario.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:37)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Los Codigos son los siguientes:

MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.propietario.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public EditText name;
public Button query_button;
public TextView result_address;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    name=findViewById(R.id.name);
    query_button=findViewById(R.id.query_button);
    result_address=findViewById(R.id.result);

    //onclicklistener
    query_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //instance of database access

            DataBaseAccess dataBaseAccess=DataBaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            dataBaseAccess.open();

            //getting string

            String n=name.getText().toString();
            String address = dataBaseAccess.getAddress(n);


            //set to textview

            result_address.setText(address);

            dataBaseAccess.close();

            //database conection closed

        }
    });
}
}
```

DatabaseOpenHelper.java :

```
package com.example.propietario.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="MyExternalDatabase.db";
private static final int  DATABASE_VERSION=1;

//constructor

public DataBaseOpenHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

}
}
```

DataBaseAccess.java :

```
package com.example.propietario.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseAccess {
private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private static DataBaseAccess instance;
Cursor c = null;

//private constructor

private DataBaseAccess(Context context){
    this.openHelper=new DataBaseOpenHelper(context);

}

//to return
public static DataBaseAccess getInstance(Context context){
    if (instance==null){
        instance=new DataBaseAccess(context);

    }
    return instance;
}

//to open database

public void open(){
    this.db=openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

}

//close database conetcion

public void close(){
    if(db!=null){
        this.db.close();
    }
}

//method to query

public String getAddress(String name){
    c=db.rawQuery("Select Address from Table1 where Name ='"+name+"'", new String[]{});
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while(c.moveToNext()){
        String address = c.getString(0);
        buffer.append(""+address);
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}

}
```

---

Agregue las lineas que indicaste, pero no estoy seguro de haberlas agregado correctamente porque sigue sin funcionar, estos son los codigos:

DatabaseOpenHelper.java:

```
package com.example.diego.databasetest2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;


public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
private static final String 
DATABASE_NAME="MyExternaldatabase.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(DataBase.CREATE_TABLE);
}

//constructor

public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}


}
```

Para poder crear y  llamar la base de datos, debo crear otra clase?

Comment: El error te indica que no has creado la tabla `table1`

Answer (score 0):

No se ha creado la tabla que intentas acceder:

> SQLiteException: no such table: Table1 (code 1)

debes realizar la creación en el método `onCreate()` de tu clase `DataBaseOpenHelper` :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

}
```

---

Debes crear tu script para crear la tabla y llamarlo desde el método `onCreate()`, ejemplo:

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE Table1 ("
        + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + "name TEXT);";
...
...

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}
```

- Es importante que cuando implementes la creación de la tabla, elimines el caché de la aplicación o la aplicación para que se pueda crear nuevamente la estructura correcta de la base de datos con la tabla.

Comment: Para la base de datos utilicé el programa "BD Browser for SQLite", y generé un archivo llamado "MyExternalDataBase.db", el cual agregué al proyecto creando una carpeta llamada "assets" y coloqué el archivo alli. luego le hago referencia en la clase DataBaseOpenHelper, o eso me parece, debo crear otra base de datos diferente?

Comment: Era importante comentar que usas SQLiteAssetHelper te sugiero agregues informacion reelevante al pregunta para te podamos ayudar de una manera mejor.

Comment: Usé el programa  BD Browser for SQLite para crear la tabla y luego agregarlo a la App creando un asset folder, como indique en el comentario anterior, no tengo mucho conocimiento por lo cual no estoy seguro de estar usando el SQLiteAssetHelper, podrias guiarme en ese aspecto?, gracias